# bootstrap-table (wenzhixin) table pagination via server don 't work

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I am trying to make a table using the library (bootstrap-table.com) to use server paging. I am using this example: https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#options/table-ajax.html#view-source

My backend code looks like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table 
    id="pedidos"
  data-toggle="table"
 data-data-type="text"
  data-url="<?php echo $url;?>/sistema/tabela_pedidos.php"
  data-side-pagination="server"
  data-pagination="true"
    >
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="pedido_data" >DATA</th>
      <th data-field="cliente_nome" >CLIENTE</th>
      <th data-field="produto_nome" >PRODUTO</th>
      <th data-field="produto_quantidade" >QUANT</th>
      <th data-field="cliente_src" >SRC</th>
      <th data-field="cliente_utm_source" >UTM_SOURCE</th>
      <th data-field="produto_preco" >PRECO</th>
      <th data-field="pagamento_tipo" >TIPO DE PAGAMENTO</th>
      <th data-field="pedido_status"  >STATUS</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>   </table></div> <!-- table -->
```

The answer from my server is this:

```
{"total":1,"totalNotFiltered":1,"rows":[{"pedido_data":"teste","cliente_nome":"teste","produto_nome":"teste","produto_quantidade":"teste","cliente_src":"teste","cliente_utm_source":"teste","produto_preco":"teste","pagamento_tipo":"teste","pedido_status":"teste"}]}
```

The example answer of the website (which works) is this:

```
{
  "total": 800,
  "totalNotFiltered": 800,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Item 0",
      "price": "$0"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Item 1",
      "price": "$1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Item 2",
      "price": "$2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Item 3",
      "price": "$3"
    }
  ]
}
```

as I see the json format is identical, but my code is not working ..

my server code looks like this:

```
<?php 

$dados = Array();
$dados['total'] = 1;
$dados['totalNotFiltered'] = 1;
$dados['rows'][] = Array('pedido_data'=>'teste','cliente_nome'=>'teste','produto_nome'=>'teste','produto_quantidade'=>'teste','cliente_src'=>'teste','cliente_utm_source'=>'teste','produto_preco'=>'teste','pagamento_tipo'=>'teste','pedido_status'=>'teste');

echo json_encode($dados,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

mysqli_close($conecta);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tried and got solution, maybe late, but hope help other like me..

```
            $dados = Array();
            $dados['total'] = 10;
            $dados['totalNotFiltered'] = 2;
            $dados['rows'] = array(
                    Array(
                            "id"=> 0,
                            "name"=> "Item 0",
                            "price"=> "$0"
                    ),
                    Array(
                            "id"=> 1,
                            "name"=> "Item 1",
                            "price"=> "$1"
                    )
            );

            echo json_encode($dados, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

i think the problem is in variable you're declare,,